# Python- "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" OR FileNotFoundError OR (unicode error)

Tags: python, python-3.x

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5PTw.png)I am getting below errors , I tried from different different steps.

Python- "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" OR FileNotFoundError OR (unicode error)

Below is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

'''download iris.csv from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/uiuc-cse/data-fa14/gh-pages/data/iris.csv'''
iris = pd.read_csv ("C:\Users\Saggar16\Desktop\caffairs\iris.csv")
```

Comment: There is a space between `pd.read_csv` and `("C:\Users\Saggar16\Desktop\caffairs\iris.csv")`.

Comment: The '\' in your string will likely cause problems as they are escape charachters

Comment: You can only get one error at a time, so please include your exact code and the corresponding, complete error traceback in your question.

Comment: @Julia Spaces between the function name and the opening parentheses aren't significant, so this doesn't cause any problem.

Comment: Hi All,
This is the only complete code . I am just downloading the data set from pasted url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
iris = pd.read_csv ("C:\\Users\\Saggar16\\Desktop\\caffairs\\iris.csv");
```

Or

```
iris = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\Saggar16\Desktop\caffairs\iris.csv");
```

Comment: While your answer is correct, I'd suggest using raw strings when specifying paths, to prevent the programmer from forgetting to escape their backslashes, like so: 
`iris = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\Saggar16\Desktop\caffairs\iris.csv")`

Comment: Thom747-
below is the code--
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np



'''download iris.csv from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/uiuc-cse/data-fa14/gh-pages/data/iris.csv'''
iris = pd.read_csv ("C:\\Users\\Saggar16\\Desktop\\caffairs\\iris.csv");

Answer (score 0):

there was path error. 
READ_CSV is used to read from local machine.
The file that I was accessing was not given path properly.